# Bootstrap navbar collapse isn't working with angular4.4.4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When I was using bootstrap3 in angular4.4.4, the bootstrap navbar collapse doesn't work, the collpased contents don't show up when I click it. Who can help me?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >
            <img src="/assets/brand/apple-touch-icon.png" width="20" height="20" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            CottonSoft
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggler-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
                    <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: You wrote "when I was using". Does this mean it worked before? Are you currently using something else?

Comment: did you imported `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run

```
npm install  bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
```

In your-project/.angular-cli.json

add the following lines:

```
    "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works for me well as you told.But I still don't understand why.I hava installed bootstrap as tutorial https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/.could you tell me why.Thank you.

Comment: That's ngx-bootstrap. It's a bootstrap container for Angular, so it doesn't have all functionalities of bootstrap . But the reason it didn't work for you is because you didn't import jquery

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help.
I'm using Angular11, with @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap and could manage to make the collapsed menu work only after installing bootstrap and jquery and referencing javascript files, as you oriented to do.